# Change cell background color if the same number or with prefix matches in another work book (ID) range Sheet2!(A2:A)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

how to highlight/alert D5 with the background color, If Cell (D5) value matches with another workbook ID range Sheet2!(A2:A). based on two criteria.

One is with a number eg.345 and another is a prefixed letter with number eg. R345

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ngvrwjC9eoLBu0gpLUdskBdkKylhoSPTjBk5sY-V3D8/edit#gid=0

[image]

Comment: In your question, the cell is "D5". But in your sample, the cell is "C5". In your actual situation, which do you want to use? And, from `based on two criteria.`, in your sample, for example, when `R345` is put in the cell "C5" and when only `345` is existing in the column "A" of 2nd sheet, you don't want to set the color?

Comment: D5 ( i have modified now)

Comment: thanks for asking! Yes I do want to set color for both scenarios (345 or R345)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? But, I have only the information from your question. So, I couldn't understand the detailed information of your actual situation. If my proposed answer was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to search the values of the column "A" of "Sheet2" using a value retrieved from the cell "D5" of "Sheet1".
- For example, when the search value is `R345`, when `345` and `R345` are found in the column "A" of "Sheet2", you want to change the background color of "D5" of "Sheet1" to the red color.

  - In this case, I thought that when the search value is not found, you might want to remove the background color.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName1 = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const sheetName2 = "Sheet2"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [sheet1, sheet2] = [sheetName1, sheetName2].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));
  const searchRange = sheet1.getRange("D5");
  const searchValue = searchRange.getValue();
  const m = typeof searchValue == "string" ? Number(searchValue.match(/(\d+)/)[1]) : searchValue;
  const search = sheet2.getRange("A2:A" + sheet2.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(`^R${m}$|^${m}$`).useRegularExpression(true).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
  searchRange.setBackground(search.length == 2 ? "red" : null);
}
```

- In this sample script, the search value is retrieved from "D5" of "Sheet1". And, the values are searched from column "A" of "Sheet2". When 2 values are found, the background color is changed to a red color.
- I used TextFinder for checking the number of searched values.

#### Note:

- The above sample script can be run with the script editor. For example, how about the following sample script? In this case, when you edit the cell "D5", the script is run by the simple trigger of OnEdit.

  ```
    function onEdit(e) {
      const sheetName1 = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
      const sheetName2 = "Sheet2"; // Please set the sheet name.

      const range = e.range;
      const sheet = range.getSheet();
      if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName1 || range.getA1Notation() != "D5") return;
      const sheet2 = e.source.getSheetByName(sheetName2);
      const searchValue = range.getValue();
      const m = typeof searchValue == "string" ? Number(searchValue.match(/(\d+)/)[1]) : searchValue;
      const search = sheet2.getRange("A2:A" + sheet2.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(`^R${m}$|^${m}$`).useRegularExpression(true).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
      range.setBackground(search.length == 2 ? "red" : null);
    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)

Comment: thanks for the script,  onEdit function works if the same number has a prefix but it is not highlighting If I enter an existing number like eg. 350, 349, 342. Basically, I want to highlight/warn and avoid duplicate log numbers before submitting the form.

Comment: @Humming Bird Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `but it is not highlighting If I enter an existing number like eg. 350, 349, 342. Basically, I want to highlight and avoid duplicate log numbers before submitting the form.,`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Humming Bird For example, when `345` is put to the cell "D5", the cell color is changed. But `350` is put, the cell color is not changed. Because both `350` and `R350` are not found in the column "A", while only the value of `350` is found. I confirmed that when I asked about this, my understanding was correct. If I  misunderstood your actual goal, I apologize.

Comment: @Humming Bird For example, when `350` is put to the cell "D5", and at least one value of `350` or `R350` is found, when you want to change the cell color, please modify `searchRange.setBackground(search.length == 2 ? "red" : null);` to `searchRange.setBackground(search.length > 0 ? "red" : null);` and test it again.

Comment: perfect! It's working now  as required :) thank you so much :)

Comment: small request on this same function, how about set bg color to another cell (instead of D5) on an edit of D5. eg if enter number in D5 then G5 cell should chage colour

Comment: @Humming Bird Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When you want to change the background folor from "D5" to other, please modify `range.setBackground(search.length == 2 ? "red" : null);` to `sheet.getRange("##").setBackground(search.length == 2 ? "red" : null);`. `##` is the cell A1Notation you want to use.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike. It works :)
````sheet.getRange("#").setBackground(search.length > 0 ? "red" : null);````

Comment: additional I have added this line ````sheet.getRange("L3").setValue("LOG Number Exists");```` But how to return Blank value (in L3) when there is no duplicate

Comment: @Humming Bird About `additional I have added this line sheet.getRange("L3").setValue("LOG Number Exists"); But how to return Blank value (in L3)back when there is no duplicate`, is this your new question?

Comment: new question but in the same function :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71544274/set-null-value-when-number-search-not-found